# How to do excel sheet like calculations in django Admin?

Tags: python, django, admin

I have a below model Student. In Django Admin can I write a code so that when user types the value of "ActualFees"
it should check if "BalanceFees" is empty . If it is empty then Paidfees should get copied in BalanceFees otherwise don't copy.

Again if "PaidFees" is typed by user then "BalanceFees" must be calculated as,

```
BalanceFees = BalanceFees - PaidFees.
```

How to write code to achive this in Django Admin?

```
class Student(models.Model):
    GENDER = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),)
    BLOOD = (
        ('O+','O+'),
        ('O-','O-'),
        ('A +','A +'),
        ('A -','A -'),
        ('B +','B +'),
        ('B -','B -'),
        ('AB +','AB +'),
        ('AB -','AB -'),
        )
    enroll_no = models.IntegerField()
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200,help_text='SurName MiddleName     First name ')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,blank = True,choices=GENDER)
    blood_gr = models.CharField(max_length=3,blank = True,choices=BLOOD)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="static",blank = True)
    ActualFees = models.IntegerField(blank = True)
    PaidFees = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    BalanceFees = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    PermenantAddress = models.TextField(blank = True)
    Parents_Mobile = models.IntegerField(blank = True,default=0)
    Personal_Mobile = models.IntegerField(blank = True,default=0)
    LocalAddress = models.TextField(blank = True)
    Parents_email = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = True,default='')
    Personal_email = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank = True,default='')

   def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this:

1. Server-side: by catching the save of the `AdminForm` and then if one field is empty calculating the appropriate other value, with validations to make sure all three fields sum to the right value. *The issue with this approach is that if a client turns of javascript they can still enter invalid data*
2. Client-side: writing some custom javascript that will catch changes to the appropriate fields and then sum accordingly on the `onblur` event.

A mix of both is probably best, and the actual implementation is left as an exercise to the reader.

To add extra scripts in, its as easy as modifying the `Media` class:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = [
                '/scripts/calculate.js',
            ]
```

Comment: I am opting for second approach as it needs to be calculated at client side and server will do as usual its own stuff. :) Now how i have to concentrate on how to hack django admin form fields in java script?

Comment: I Have done it my calculate.js is up and running i have put demo code as alert("Hello World!"), after writing some lines in urls.py, and settings.py and after googling , this calculate.js is running. Now How  to access this ActualFees text box in calculate.js??

Comment: def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.BalanceFees=obj.BalanceFees-obj.PaidFees
           obj.save()                                                                                                                this is good but how to check if BalanceFees is nothing?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it. I have edited  models.py  and added default = 0 in Student models PaidFees 
and BalanceFees fields. After adding these fields I have perform migrations and all. Also my Previous data remains as it is.
I can do calculations in save_model method in admin.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ....
    ....
    ....

    PaidFees = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
    BalanceFees = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
    ....
    ....

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if obj.BalanceFees == 0:
        obj.BalanceFees = obj.ActualFees
    else:
        obj.BalanceFees = obj.BalanceFees-obj.PaidFees
    obj.save()
```

Still I am curious to know the solution at client side.